# Positioning Several Images Inside a Div Block

Tags: image, positioning, block

I want to position several images inside a div block. The position of the images inside it should be relative to that div.

Should I put each image inside a block of its own size and position those blocks relatively to the bigger block? (So in any browser the block will look the same!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Here's a simple mock up.

the Html

```
<div>
<img src="/1st.jpg">
<img src="/2nd.jpg">
<img src="/3rd.jpg">
</div>
```

The css

```
div { display: block; }

img { display: inline-block; position: relative; float: left; }
```

Comment: Yeh thanks but if I want them to be positioned in certain distance from the borders and from each other, should I make a class so I wont add the values individually?

Comment: Ya, but there will be more blocks so I made a class for the images for this block specifically (other bigger blocks will have other specifications).

.imagesBlock1 {
position:relative;
width: 55px;
height: 55px;
margin: 4px; 
display: inline-block;
position: relative; 
float: left; 
}

Comment: It's better to learn how to use properly classes and IDs , so it'll be as small and efficient as possible. So, thanks!